# Python Pandas KeyError when trying to save a timestamp to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I'm trying to save a data frame to a mysql database. But it seems that it doesn't work because of the timestamp (format?).

```
stock_hist = pd.io.data.get_data_yahoo('company', start = datetime.datetime(2010,1,1), end = datetime.datetime(2015,01,01))
stock_hist.to_sql('table', dbCon, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

When I run this script, the following Error occurs
.....

```
in escape_item
    encoder = encoders[type(val)]
KeyError: <class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

Can't figure it out and couldn't find a similar answer...

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? This should normally be fixed in >= 0.15 (it was a bug in 0.14)

Comment: I'm thought I was using 0.15. But the version check showed 0.14.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating pandas from 0.14.1 to 0.15.2 as advised by joris worked.